# convert string to timestamp and add it as parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using two databases one as a main database and the second as a branch. i add a table to save a timestamp for every database. what i need is to get data from database to sync it in the branches according to the **last syc timestamp** in every branch. i get the last timestamp from the databases as a string. what i need is to send this timestamp to the main database (web server). how can i convert this string to timestamp in c# or if there is another way like to add this timestamp as varchar parameter and convert it in the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse` methods will let you convert `string` to `datetime`. The other way around is simply a `.ToString` on the `DateTime`, you can also provide formats if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is by getting the timestamp from database converted to varchar using **master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(cast(timeStampVariable as varbinary(8)))** then send it to the other database as string where i need to store it as a string in a parameter table... thanks for all who try to help.